# Oracle DB hangs on last request from Spark and Java

Tags: java, oracle, scala, apache-spark

Please help, I'm clueless.

I use Spark with ojdbc8-12.2.0.1 driver to read data from Oracle.

Set fetch size 5000.
Everything works well until the very last moment to get that final batch of 5000 records and the process just hangs.

I also tried to implement simple reader using Scala and ojdbc11:23.2.0.0 library.

Same thing. No matter what fetch size I set, everything works well until that last piece of data where Oracle DB simply does not respond.

Example: I query a subset of data that contains 499 records, I set fetch size 100, I receive first 400 records but last 99 records request just hangs without response.

I tried to use Connection.setNetworkTimeout in Scala code to break connection if Oracle does not respond for last 10 seconds. Indeed, Oracle does not respond on the very last request.

What can be the reason?

Comment: This doesn't sound like a database problem, since Oracle is more likely to hang on the first row than the last row. To confirm, run this query a few times: `select elapsed_time/1000000 seconds, gv$sql.* from gv$sql where users_executing > 0 order by elapsed_time desc;` If the SECONDS keeps increasing, the database is the cause. If the SECONDS does not increase, the query is waiting for the client to request more rows. If you can't find your query at all, then the database has already closed the cursor and I'm not sure why your application is still waiting.

Comment: Agree, almost certainly a client-issue. Next time it "hangs", find your session in `v$session` and look at the `status` field. Does it say `INACTIVE`? You can also look at `event` and `state`.. if `state` = `WAITING` and `event` is  `SQL*Net message from client` , the database is not doing anything. It's waiting on your client. You'd have to investigate on the client-side. Lastly, you can do a 10046 trace to see the calls the client is making and you can identify whether or not that last FETCH operation was ever made and if so whether `r=` (rows) is what you expect.

Comment: Thank you for help. I have figured out the problem and solution. Posted as answer.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot explain very strange behaviour of the client driver library but I know the cause of my issue:

Oracle DB table SampleTable with column batch_id VARCHAR2(10).

The issue is reproduced when send a query with filter using numeric values. E.g.:

```sql
SELECT * FROM SampleTable WHERE batch_id = 10
```

Say there are 25 records, our fetch size is 10, we will receive 20 records and then the process just hangs.

If we would change request to use correct condition type string instead of number, then the problem disappears:

```
SELECT * FROM SampleTable WHERE batch_id = '10'
```

Now we are able to fetch all 25 records without any problem.

Here is Scala sample code:

```scala
package com.sample

import java.sql.Connection
import oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource

object App {
  
  def main(args : Array[String]) {
    val query = "SELECT * FROM SampleTable WHERE batch_id = '10'"
    // Failing query: "SELECT * FROM SampleTable WHERE batch_id = 10"

    val ods = new OracleDataSource()
    ods.setURL("jdbc:oracle:thin:@//{oracle_db_host}:{port}/{database}")
    ods.setUser("username")
    ods.setPassword("password")

    val connection = ods.getConnection()
    val statement = connection.createStatement()

    statement.setFetchSize(10)

    val resultSet : java.sql.ResultSet = statement.executeQuery(query)
    resultSet.next()

    var num = 0
    do {
      num += 1
      println("Record number: " + num)
    } while (resultSet.next)
  }
}
```

Built with Maven dependecy:

```xml
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
   <artifactId>ojdbc11</artifactId>
   <version>23.2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```